# Noise Activated Software

Tags: windows, audio, automation, microphone

I read about a piece of software a while ago that a guy developed that would listen for his dog to start barking or making noise, and then play back a prerecording message of him telling the dog to be quiet.  He used it to keep the dog quiet while he was gone to work.

What I am looking for is a program that can respond to "noise" events via the microphone and then perform specific actions such as playing another sound.  It doesn't need to be this original dog orientated program.  Anyone know of such a program?

I am running Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Windows Vista or 7 you can use speech macros (mostly) built into Windows.

See: [Set up Speech Recognition](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Set-up-Speech-Recognition), [What can I do with Speech Recognition?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/What-can-I-do-with-Speech-Recognition) and [Windows Speech Recognition Macros](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fad62198-220c-4717-b044-829ae4f7c125&displaylang=en).

HTH